# regex to validate HTTP request string in C?

Tags: c, regex, http

I don't know much about regex but I know how it's useful. I want to validate HTTP requests like this one in C.

```
GET /foo.html HTTP/1.1
```

Following things are compulsory

1. GET
2. "/"
3. file extension (period in file path)
4. HTTP/1.1
5. Only two spaces, one after GET and another after filepath.

I wrote code without regex, it's really messy, it uses strncmp, 2 for loops and some bools to validate request. I still can't figure out how to verify HTTP/1.1 though. Here's the code (note - "line" is char array which stores the HTTP request)

```
// validate request-line
        if (strncmp(line, "GET", 3) != 0)
            error(405);
        if (line[3] != ' ')
            error(400);
        if (line[4] != '/')
            error(501);

        // Initializing some variable for future use
        bool period = false;
        int y = strlen(line);
        bool secondspace = false;

        // quotes not allowed
        for (int z = 0; z < y; z++)
        {
            if (line[z] == '"')
                error(400);
        }

        // check for period in file path
        for (int x = 4; x < y ; x++)
        {
            if (secondspace != true)
            {
                if (line[x] == '.')
                {
                    period = true;
                }
            }
            if (line[x] != ' ')
            {
                secondspace = true;
            }

        }
        if (period != true)
            error(501);
        if (secondspace != true)
            error(400);
```

Comment: do I assume correctly that you not only want to validate, but also extract the information?

Comment: Kind of. I want to validate those 5 things and if any of them isn't valid , respective error must be sent.

Comment: And, ladies and gentlemen, that's how you respond without actually adressing the question...

Comment: @Nem A period doesn't guarantee a file extension.

Comment: @Karoly Yeah you can assume that I also want to extract information.

Comment: @cad I know but there is another function in code which validates if the file exists or not. So it's okay to assume period = file extension exists for now ;)

Comment: @Nem And what if the period was the last character?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PCRE C-API. (latest is 10.10)

Download page: ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/

I show you my own 'preg_match' function which use this API:

```
int preg_match( char *pattern, char *subject, char *match ) {
  int rc, error;
  PCRE2_SIZE erroffset, *ovector;
  pcre2_code *re;
  pcre2_match_data *match_data;

  size_t len = strlen( (char *) subject );

  re = pcre2_compile( (PCRE2_SPTR) pattern, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, 0, &error, &erroffset, NULL );

  if ( !re ) {
    syslog( LOG_ERR, "preg_match(): pcre_compile failed (offset: %zu), %d", erroffset, error );
    return (-1);
  }

  match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern( re, NULL );

  rc = pcre2_match( re, (PCRE2_SPTR) subject, len, 0, 0, match_data, NULL );

  if ( rc < 0 ) {
    switch ( rc ) {
      case PCRE2_ERROR_NOMATCH:
        syslog( LOG_ERR, "preg_match(): Pattern '%s' no match!", pattern );
        break;
      default:
        syslog( LOG_ERR, "preg_match(): Matching error %d!", rc );
        break;
    }

    pcre2_match_data_free( match_data );
    pcre2_code_free( re );
    return (-2);
  }

  ovector = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer( match_data );

  PCRE2_SPTR substring_start = (PCRE2_SPTR) subject + ovector[2];
  size_t substring_length = ovector[3] - ovector[2];
  sprintf( match, "%.*s", (int) substring_length, (char *) substring_start );

  pcre2_match_data_free( match_data );
  pcre2_code_free( re );

  return (rc);
}
```

And you can use in a C program this way:

```
int main() {
  char *match,
       *pattern,
       *subject;

  pattern = "GET /(\\S*) HTTP/1.1";
  subject = "GET /foo.html HTTP/1.1";

  match = (char *) malloc(100);
  memset( match, 0, sizeof( match ) );

  if ( preg_match( pattern, subject, match ) > 0 ) {
    printf("File: %s\n", match);
  }
  else {
    printf("No match!\n");
  }

  free( match );

  return (0);
}
```

Output:

> File: foo.html